# Spring Data Jpa OneToMany Saving New Child To Persisted Parent Updates Parent

Tags: java, spring, jpa, spring-data-jpa, one-to-many

When i add new car to persisted person and save car from car repository, person gets updated too. Why this happens or should be happen?

```
@Entity
public class Person implements Serializable {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    private String firstName;

    private String lastName;

    private String identityNumber;

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "identityNumber", referencedColumnName = "identityNumber")
    private List<Car> cars = new ArrayList<>();

    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    private Status status;

    public enum Status{
        SINGLE,
        MARRIED
    }

    public void addCar(Car car){
        cars.add(car);
    }
}

@Entity
public class Car {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    private String model;

    private String identityNumber;
}
```

```
        String identityNumber = UUID.randomUUID().toString();

        Person person = Person.builder()
                .firstName("affasf")
                .lastName("asdasdsa")
                .status(Person.Status.SINGLE)
                .identityNumber(identityNumber)
                .cars(new ArrayList<>())
                .build();

        personRepository.save(person);

        Car car = Car.builder()
                .identityNumber(identityNumber)
                .model("BMW").build();

        person.addCar(car);

        person.setStatus(Person.Status.MARRIED);

        carRepository.save(car);

        return person;
```

I'm just trying to understand that is it expected behavior, if it's why? I couldn't find much on google. Thank you for your answers by advance.

Note : I removed the lombok annotations to keep the code shorter.

Comment: Any change in entity’s attributes denotes a change in the entity itself.

Comment: JPA is managing this for you in the backend.

Comment: After some more research, can we say that, after i changed the property of the person object and then saved the car object, the person object was also updated in the database, cuz the person object was still in the persistence context?